# Get non file body from multipart/form-data using AWS API Gateway and Lambda

Tags: forms, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to get the form data from a `multipart/form-data` `POST` to my ASW Lambda web service via API Gateway.

The HTTP `POST` has Content-Type "multipart/form-data" and body that is URL encoded. File data is also sent in this post (hence the multipart, I guess).

The web service needs to integrate with a thirdparty service, so changing the format of the `POST` isn't really an option.

I have seen this [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=673012&tstart=0#673012) talking about converting the URL encoded data to JSON object for use in Lambda, but this doesn't do the trick.

I have also tried setting the *Integration Request* -> *Mapping Templates* for content type `multipart/form-data` to *Input passthrough*. This didn't help either.

I did come across another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31645205/8524) about uploading a file using `multipart/form-data`, but since I'm not interested in the file, just the body, that answer didn't help.

Below find screenshot (sorry) of the captured post via runscope.

[image: Post details]

Comment: Can you show an example of the post body?

Comment: @Ryan updated with screenshot of post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the goal is to use Lambda, you'll need to pass valid JSON to the function. Currently there isn't a way to JSON-ify data inside Api Gateway that comes in as non-JSON data.

Our short term fix (on our backlog) is to provide a variable in the mapping templates to grab the raw input of the request. That way you could do a simple JSON conversion using a template like:

```
{
    "body" : "$input.body"
}
```

or something like that.

Check out the mapping template reference for more info: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

Edit 4/7 - feature has been released as $input.body

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suspected that it was a JSON only service. (Not too unreasonable given the direction most Web APIs are heading.)  
I worked around this restriction by putting another service in between, that does the translation.

Comment: Hi @Jack  is this `$input.raw` variable available yet?

Comment: Not yet, we're still working on getting through a lot of other items on the backlog. No ETA at this point, unfortunately. My apologies!

Comment: Hey @JackKohn-AWS, I think without this feature there's no way to use signatures to verify incoming requests from webhooks like Github - https://developer.github.com/webhooks/securing/ . This is a pretty limiting feature for us. Any updated ETA on this?

Comment: To answer my own question above, AWS has added a mapping called `"$input.body"`, see - https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=228067

Comment: @Diederik can you tell exactly which service did you use to do the translation?

Comment: The solution is to use a mapping template to get the whole (non-JSON as I understand it - disclaimer, I didn't use this workaround for now) body passed to Lambda.  

(The service the Lambda interacted with was a third-party service, so I couldn't change what it was sending the function.)