# Upload image to Lambda using gateway API

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to let user upload pictures to a lambda function for processing; using the gateway API interface.

I tried to specify a model for my POST method, but so far I keep getting the error

> Invalid model specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors : [Invalid model schema specified]

... Not so helpful.

I understand that I cannot directly send raw data to lambda and must using some kind of formatting in-between.

What I understood is that I could make the gateway interface base64 encode the data for me.

I tried to do so by using the following model schema with the content type image/jpeg

```
{
    "body" : $util.base64Encode($input.body)
}
```

How to send the image ?

Comment: A better solution would be to upload the pictures in S3 and then process it with Lambda. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31645205/how-to-upload-file-to-lambda-function-or-api-gateway

Comment: It seems either using s3 or performing base64 before upload is necessary.  Base64 consume more bandwidth and s3 force us to perform additional requests...

Comment: Wrapping `$util.base64Encode($input.body)` in quotes will solve the issue: `"body": "$util.base64Encode($input.body)"`. However, the encoded data is corrupt and useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native support in API Gateway for binary data as you have seen. We are working on this but I don't have an ETA for you. Some customers have had success base64 encoding the data like you have in your question, only it should be in a mapping template in the Integration Request **not** the Method Request.

If you set the content type to image/jpeg, then the encoding will apply only when the Content-Type header on the incoming request is also image/jpeg, so make sure to set that.

You can also reject incoming requests to the method that **don't** send the right Content Type by setting the 'Request body passthrough' (passthroughBehavior in the API) to the recommended value ("when there are no templates defined" or 'WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES' in the API)

Docs for the passthrough behavior -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration/#passthroughBehavior

Comment: I was able to base64-encode png image and send it to lambda.  Lambda then decodes it and stores the image somewhere in s3. But that image is corrupt. 
In other words, `base64Encode` doesn't work correctly for binary data. Not sure how some of your customers have had success base64 encoding the data...

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems like working with binary data and API Gateway is complicated, I think you should:

1. Upload the image using [API Gateway as an S3 proxy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html)
2. Set a trigger for your lambda function on PUT for the bucket where you've uploaded the image